# Can I get a local patent for a design in Nigeria

Tags: patentability

Can I file for a patent when I only have the CAD rendering and not the real design? This is specific for Nigeria.

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively, but I would assume you only need drawings. You should consider consulting with a Nigerian patent attorney.

Comment: Nigeria a member or signatory of the Paris Convention, WIPO, PCT, Rome Convention, Berne Convention, etc. so I would expect their procedures and standards to be very similar to other countries. https://www.wipo.int/treaties/en/ShowResults.jsp?country_id=128C

Comment: Patent drawings do not need to be to scale or show production-level detail that is not required to enable someone skilled in the art to make and use the invention. Besides drawings of a specific embodiment a good patent application has more generic drawings, drawings that clearly illustrate important mechanisms, and drawings showing variations and alternate embodiments. Patent drawings are their own specific type of drawing but your CAD drawings are a very good starting point for a skilled patent draftsperson to start from.

Comment: When you say "design" are you talking about an invention - the way something works and achieves a technical result, or a decorative, ornamental design based on esthetics rather than function?

Comment: Thanks George white. I meant the mechanism. I will do as told